# What is a "context" in this context: "symbol.context([context])"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to load and append external SVGs to an existing SVG in an Electron project. The `d3.xml` methods are not working for me so I am looking at [d3.symbols](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#symbols), hoping that if I provide the path data (from an [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) call) I can create my own symbols.

Looking at the docs I don't understand what "context" refers to. Is it an element like a `g` (group)? Is it the top-level SVG?

Foundering around a bit here.

> **symbol.context([context])**
>
> If context is specified, sets the context and returns this symbol
>   generator. If context is not specified, returns the current context,
>   which defaults to null. If the context is not null, then the generated
>   symbol is rendered to this context as a sequence of path method calls.
>   Otherwise, a path data string representing the generated symbol is
>   returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the new additions to `d3` version 4 was the ability to draw directly to an HTML5 canvas element.  Previous versions primarily dealt with only drawing using `SVG`.  The `.context` calls expect an HTML5 canvas context and then subsequent drawing activities will be made on that canvas.  If it is `null` (as it is by default) then `d3` assumes you are drawing to svg and returns the path data for a later call to `.attr("d", pathDataString)`.

From the version 4 [CHANGES document](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md):

> Shapes are no longer limited to SVG; they can now render to Canvas! Shape generators now support an optional context: given a CanvasRenderingContext2D, you can render a shape as a canvas path to be filled or stroked. For example, a canvas pie chart might use an arc generator:

Comment: Ah, ok. got it. Thanks!